# Force JacksonXml to serialize raw value as string

Tags: java, json, xml, fasterxml, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have some XML being provided to me from an external system, which I need to parse. One of the values contains some HTML (unencoded) which Jackson is having problems with:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<lookup_info>-- [Snipped] --------------<BR/>
Some more snipped data.<BR/>
<BR/>
And some more snipped data..<BR/>
<BR/>
And even more snipped data...</lookup_info>
```

My code works fine for all fields except this one, my pojo code looks like:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "customer_name")
private String customerName;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "email")
private String email;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "lookup_info")
private String lookupInfo;
```

If I change `lookupInfo` to type `Object`, I can see Jackson is mapping the raw data to a `LinkedHashMap`... With one entry, `{BR=null}`

How can I force Jackson to serialize the raw value to `String`? I've tried with `@JacksonXmlText` and that results in `lookupInfo` being `null`.

Comment: did you find a solution? i'm facing a similiar problem. in my case i want to deserialize a sub-node (xml) as raw xml...

Comment: @RomanAgapkin: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @sbhatt no, unfortunately not. used a complete different approach

Comment: @RomanAgapkin Thanks for your quick response, can I know what was the different approach.. was it something other then JacksonXML ?

Comment: @sbhatt i don't think, the different approach is for you :-) it is more a workaround. i've ignored the field in deserialization and initialized it afterwards "manually"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your xml is invalid.  if you want html content embedded within an xml element, then you need to properly *encode* the content.  if you are generating the content, then any reasonable xml generator should handle that encoding for you.

you xml should look something like:

```
<lookup_info>-- [Snipped] --------------&lt;BR/&gt;
Some more snipped data.&lt;BR/&gt;
&lt;BR/&gt;
And some more snipped data..&lt;BR/&gt;
&lt;BR/&gt;
And even more snipped data...</lookup_info>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library. It has a static method `U.fromXmlMap(xml)`. I am the maintainer of the project.

Output map:

```
{
  "lookup_info": {
    "#text": "-- [Snipped] --------------",
    "BR": [
      {
        "-self-closing": "true"
      },
      {
        "#item": {
          "#text1": "\nSome more snipped data."
        }
      },
      {
        "-self-closing": "true"
      },
      {
        "-self-closing": "true"
      },
      {
        "#item": {
          "#text2": "\nAnd some more snipped data.."
        }
      },
      {
        "-self-closing": "true"
      },
      {
        "-self-closing": "true"
      }
    ],
    "#text3": "\nAnd even more snipped data..."
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```